# AI chat bot that answers by focusing only on 30 textbooks

Tags: training, transformer, chat-bots, transfer-learning, fine-tuning

I don't even know what I'm looking for and what's the terminology, so here I am asking this question.

## Background

Assume I have 30 textbooks. I want to have an AI chatbot like ChatGPT which answers the questions that I ask from those 30 textbooks. I mean I don't want to ask questions from outside those 30 textbooks. Moreover, I don't expect the AI chatbot to answer based on anything other than those 30 textbooks. However, I want the AI chatbot to be as intelligent as ChatGPT or other popular ones.

Maybe I want the AI chatbot to limit their attention to those 30 textbooks while answering my questions. Right? I'm not sure.

## Question

What keywords should I look for? What free or open-source models can I use? What's the procedure to create my own AI chatbot for those 30 textbooks? Am I missing anything else regarding the tools to achieve my objectives? I'd appreciate any help or hints. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this is what I'm looking for: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the machine-generated answers. Sorry if you are not getting a human answer, but there is no point in posting machine answers on Stack Exchange, unless you are 100% certain of their correctness. Anyone else can just ask the chatbot too . . . and that's fine, sometimes you can get progress at least on your issue, even if all you get is a search term like "fine tuning". A curated machine answer, which has been checked for accuracy by an expert, would be OK

Comment: @NeilSlater Right. Makes sense :)

Comment: "Vector databases", "text embeddings", "RAG" - and some clever prompts?

Comment: OpenAIs GPTs? https://openai.com/blog/introducing-gpts

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Wow! The [GPTs](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-gpts) may be really promising :)